Inline code in VS Code displays as whited out
My VS Code started randomly whiting-out anything formatted as inline code today. I didn't make any changes to my settings and I can't find this problem anywhere online. The text appears if I highlight it, but it's super annoying to have to do that.
Example of white-out:

Example when selecting text:

I first noticed it while using Github Copilot today, but then noticed it in my settings as well.How do I get it to display normally?

try starting it in safemode. do you have any extensions or high contrast mode set?

Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question. See the formatting documentation for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.
